# Is it possible to deserialize mappings using Nest 5 against Elasticsearch 5, but with indices upgraded from 2.x?

Tags: c#, .net, json, elasticsearch, nest

We have an Elasticsearch cluster that was upgraded from 2.x to 5.x. When asked for the mapping for one of the indexes, Elasticsearch returns a mapping that has a feature that applies to 2.x, and this causes Nest deserialization to fail.

Specifically, the mapping from ES has a dynamic_template with a fielddata that contains the "format" property. The "format" property no longer exists in 5.x.

Here's a snippet of the mapping:

```
"dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "message_field": {
          "match": "message",
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "fielddata": {
              "format": "disabled" // PROBLEM HERE!
            },
            "index": "analyzed",
            "omit_norms": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
```

Upon attempting to deserialize this, I get the following: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Error reading boolean. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'fielddata', line 15, position 30.`

This makes sense, because in 5.x, `fielddata` can only contain a boolean.

Since we're on ES 5.x, I need Nest 5.x. But I sometimes need to work with indices upgraded from 2.x.

Is there a way I can deserialize 2.x-upgraded index mappings with Nest 5? If not, what workarounds would you suggest?

Comment: What version of NEST are you using?

Comment: Using Nest 5.5.0